# How to rid of spaces in line, python

Tags: python

there are lines and in line there are spaces, so i want to get rid of spaces to left just strings.

spaces like '', '', ''
so which code should i use to delete spaces?

Thnks

Comment: Perhaps you could include some example lines, paired with expected output? It's not clear what exactly you are asking for here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
st = " with, or,  without ,  spaces            ";
st = st.replace(" ","")
print(st)
with,or,without,spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
sys.stdout.write("something")
sys.stdout.write("without")
sys.stdout.write("spaces")
```

instead of

```
print "something", "without", "spaces"
```